# Use an exported JS function in another JS file

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have the following structure in my project:

--> map
----> map.js
----> cell.js

The map.js is responsible for creating a 2D array which each position is a Cell object (cell.js).

In my cell.js I have the code below:

```
export function Cell(x, y, w) {}
```

and in my map.js, when iterating on each position I create a new instance, like the example below:

```
import { Cell } from './cell.js';
...
board[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, w);
...
```

And finally, in my index.html I just declare both of the scripts in the head tag:

```
...
<head>
 <script src="map/cell.js"></script>
 <script src="map/map.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I open the index.html (double-click in the file) on Google Chrome, it shows me the following errors in the console:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export (cell.js:1)**
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { (map.js:1)**

What do I need still to do to be able to use both the Javascript functions?

Comment: add `type="module"` attribute to your script tags.

Comment: I've added the `type="module"` in both scripts declaration and now I am facing this error: **Access to Script MY-SCRIPT-PATH from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: start chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` (for development purposes only) or use a (potentially local) webserver to host the files. There are also tons of other questions discussing CORS issues.